# What is the SimpleDateFormat pattern that parses like the deprecated String constructor for Date?

Tags: java

I have some code that looks like `"Sat May 12 04:46:05 EDT 2012"` that is currently being parsed by the `java.util.Date`'s [`Date(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29) constructor. However, now I am getting a warning in my IDE since it says that it is deprecated and the JavaDoc says:

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s).

I tried using the `SimpleDateFormatter` but the default formatter is causing an exception, so I want to try using a pattern, but what is the pattern to parse like the String constructor does?

---

NB: this is different from other similar questions because it is specifically asking about replacing a deprecated (and popular) constructor, not just asking for help parsing an arbitrary date string.

Comment: Ummm.. You would rather enjoy working with dates using [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @RohitJain legacy code with no unit tests so it must be risk adverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is `EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss zzz YYYY` so you can construct it using `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss zzz YYYY")`.

So code like

> Date d = new Date( "Sat May 12 04:46:05 EDT 2012" );

can be rewritten to:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss z YYYY" );
Date d = df.parse( "Sat May 12 04:46:05 EDT 2012" );
```

---

**edit:** from the [`java.util.Date.parse(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) JavaDoc it turns out that the method `accepts many syntaxes;` so there will be no *single* matching pattern for all invocations you will encounter. May need to fiddle with the given pattern using the documentation from [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: When rewriting your code, be aware that the SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe.

Comment: Just a really minor comment, this format also works with only one `z`.