# Formatting date with time zone. Wrong format

Tags: java

I have tried many different types of solutions using [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but couldn't quite get it right.

The input string I receive is `Tue Nov 5 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013`.
The format that I want is `dd-MMM-yy`.
Below is the code that I use:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
date = formatter.parse(s);
System.out.println(date);
```

I receive an `error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        date = formatter.parse(s);`

I tried a lot of change in my formats but still I receive this error. Can anyone please let me know the exact format of the string that I am passing?

Comment: You're getting a *compile-time* error. That doesn't depend on the format you're using. It just means that your source code is invalid - `SimpleDateFormat.parse` can throw `ParseException`, and you're neither catching it nor declaring that it can be thrown.

Comment: Note that printing out the `Date` won't help much - you'll need to use a separate `SimpleDateFormat` with your "target" format.

Comment: My bad! I forgot to add the ` try catch `block. Thanks for spotting.

Comment: @Freakyuser Please search StackOverflow before posting. Any of hundreds of Questions and Answers have example code that you could have studied to see the handling of exceptions during date-time string parsing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ParseException Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116652/parseexception-java). And this one, [ParseException; must be caught (Try/Catch) (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16112676/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you. Before I posted question, I had handled exception, which is a basic thing. While posted, it was my mistake that I missed it. Actual thing in my mind was the mistake in the format I made. For that if you want to re-edit my question.

Comment: @Freakyuser That format issue has also been handled in hundreds of Questions and Answers, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14366655/642706). Again, please search before posting. StackOverflow is getting polluted with needless duplicate questions.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have flagged my own question. Thank you once again for pointing out. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @Freakyuser In a comment you said your real problem was the format, not the ParseException. Not so. I tried your code while adding a Try-Catch (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26796539/642706) for the code). Your format works, as-is, with your given input string. So indeed, your only problem is not handling the exception as explained in the [correct accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26781113/642706).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Handle Exceptions

You have not handled exceptions in your code. That is why the compiler gives errors. You need to [handle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) the [ParseException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) that may be thrown during parsing.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
try{
   date = formatter.parse(s);
   System.out.println(date);
}catch(ParseException ex){
  //exception
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you can add  `throws ParseException`  to your method .

According to your comment it seems to be you are trying to convert a date[String] to another format. If I am correct then the following example may help you.

```
String inputstring="Tue Nov 5 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat outformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
try {
    String result = outformat.format(formatter.parse(inputstring));
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
04-Nov-13
```

Comment: Probably better not to encourage the OP to have an empty `catch` block.

Comment: @khelwood yeah! now i added it

Comment: +1 Thank you. I get an output of `Mon Nov 24 18:30:00 GMT 2014`. The date is subtracted by one. Should I change the locale?

Comment: @Freakyuser can you clarify.

Answer (score 0):

## No Problem

Your code works* if you catch the exception as directed in the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26781113/642706).

```
String input = "Tue Nov 5 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013";
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdformatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy" , Locale.ENGLISH );
java.util.Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdformatter.parse( input );
} catch ( ParseException ex ) {
    System.out.println( "ERROR: " + ex ); // … handle exception
}
System.out.println( "date: " + date + "  (adjusted to Kolkata time via Joda-Time: " + new DateTime( date , DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) );
```

When run.

```
date: Mon Nov 04 10:30:00 PST 2013  (adjusted to Kolkata time via Joda-Time: 2013-11-05T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

## Joda-Time

That same format works in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.5.

The java.util.Date/.Calendar/java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

```
String input = "Tue Nov 5 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zZ yyyy" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
```

When run.

```
dateTime: 2013-11-05T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

## Alternate Format

In your case, you could ignore the `UTC` as it is redundant with the offset ( `+0530` ). An offset is assumed to be from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). You can ignore characters by using quote marks.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'UTC'Z yyyy" );
```

---

*Your code works for me using Java 8 Update 25. Earlier versions of java.text.SimpleDateFormat had varying behaviors with the Z-letter and offsets. But, again, you should not even be using SimpleDateFormat.